# Is there a way to look for Minecraft players who we met earlier?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

PLEASE HELP ME I NEED TO LOOK FOR Barnard_plays_303 or Barnard_Plays_303 or Bardnard_playz_303 . Something like that but I don't remember . Please help me , please!!!

Comment: What exactly do you try to do? What do you need this for? What do you expect to happen when you accomplish your goal?

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:\Users[PC USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\logs and open the txt file "latest", from there press CTRL+F and search for their name.